# My for loop is not working, not sure what is wrong

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have written this code to eliminate columns based on header names. On one workbook I have the list of headers to delete, and on the other workbook I have the columns themselves.

```
'setup

    Dim nominas_ws As Worksheet
    Set nominas_ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim conceptos_wb As Workbook
    Set conceptos_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\deepw\Desktop\nominas\conceptos.xlsx")
    Dim conceptos_ws As Worksheet
    Set conceptos_ws = conceptos_wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim nominas_last_row, nominas_last_column, conceptos_last_row, conceptos_last_column As Long
            
    nominas_last_row = nominas_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    nominas_last_column = nominas_ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    conceptos_last_row = conceptos_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    conceptos_last_column = conceptos_ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
'delete names & unwanted columns

    nominas_ws.Range("C2:C" & nominas_last_row).ClearContents
    
    Dim conceptos_headers As Range
    Dim i, c As Integer
    Dim concepto_input As String
    
    For i = 2 To conceptos_last_row
        concepto_input = conceptos_ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For c = 1 To nominas_last_column
            If Cells(c, 1).Value = "concepto_input" Then Cells(c, 1).EntireColumn.delete
        Next c
    Next i
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly does "not working mean? Check the value of `conceptos_last_row` before the loop starts. Side note: `You can't `Dim` a bunch of variables at once. Try `Dim nominas_last_row As Long, nominas_last_column  As Long` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If Cells(c, 1).Value = "concepto_input" Then`

you are checking for the string literal "concepto_input", not the value in the variable `concepto_input`.  Should be:

`If Cells(c, 1).Value = concepto_input Then`

If there might be multiple matches for any given column heading, you should loop backwards:

```vb
For i = 2 To conceptos_last_row
    concepto_input = conceptos_ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    For c = nominas_last_column To 1 Step -1
        If conceptos_ws.Cells(c, 1).Value = concepto_input Then 
            conceptos_ws.Columns(c).Delete
            'Exit For 'if there can only be one match per search term
        End If
    Next c
Next i
```

Note it's also good practise to never use `Range`/`Cells` without an explicit worksheet qualifier.